# Efficiently Sort Collection in C# by Substring and Index

Tags: c#, sorting, xamarin

I'm fetching some records from my database using entity framework as the user types into a searchbox and need to sort the items as they are fetched. I'll try to simplify the problem with the below.

Say I have a random list like the below that I would like to sort in place according to the occurrence of a substring

```
var randomList = new List<string> { "corona", "corolla", "pecoroll", "copper", "capsicum", "because", "cobra" };
var searchText = "cor";
```

Sort:

```
var sortedList = testList.OrderBy(x => x.IndexOf("cor"));
```

Output:

copper -> capsicum -> because -> cobra -> corona -> corolla -> pecoroll

I understand the code works as expected since the list is sorted by the index of the substring which is -1 for the first 4 items in the output, 0 for the 5th and 6th, and 2 for the 7th item.

Problem:

I'm trying to actually sort by the index of the searchsString and it's closest match to provide the user with suggestions of similar items. The expected result would be something like

corolla -> corona -> pecoroll -> cobra -> copper -> capsicum -> because

where the items containing lower indexes of the matching searchtext would appear first  **and**  recursively sort the list by 1 less character from the searchText until no characters remain. i.e. priority given to index of "cor" then "co" then "c". 
I can probably write a for loop or recursive method for this but is there a built in LINQ method to achieve this objective on a collection or a library that handles searches this way considering that my code fetches records from a database so performance  should be considerd? Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To strictly address your question: "is there a built in LINQ method to achieve this(?)", I believe the answer is no. This type of "best match" search is very subjective; for example it could be argued that "cobra" is a better match than "pecoroll" since the user is more likely to have missed a "b" before the required "r", rather than excluding the first two letters, "pe" of the word "pecoroll". I believe that "proper" implementations of this behavior consider key proximity, common misspellings, and any number of other metrics to best auto-complete the entry. There may well be some established libraries available rather than developing your own method.

However, assuming you did want the exact behavior you requested, and whilst it sounds as if you were happy to do this yourself, here is my two cents:

```
static List<string> SortedList(List<string> baseList, string searchString)
{
    // Take a modifiable copy of the base list
    List<string> sourceList = new List<string>(baseList);
    // Sort it first alphabetically to resolve tie-breakers
    sourceList.Sort();
    // Create a instance of our list to be returned
    List<string> resultList = new List<string>();

    while(
            // While there are still elements to be sorted
            (resultList.Count != baseList.Count) &&
            // And there are characters remaining to be searched for
            (searchString.Length > 0))
    {
        // Order the list elements, that contain the full search string,
        // by the index of that search string.
        var sortedElements =  from item in sourceList
                              where item.Contains(searchString)
                              orderby item.IndexOf(searchString)
                              select item;

        // For each of the ordered elements, remove it from the source list
        // and add it to the result
        foreach(var sortedElement in sortedElements)
        {
            sourceList.Remove(sortedElement);
            resultList.Add(sortedElement);
        }

        // Remove one character from the search to be used against remaining elements
        searchString = searchString.Remove(searchString.Length - 1, 1);
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

Testing with:

```
var randomList = new List<string> { "corona", "corolla", "pecoroll", "copper", "capsicum", "because", "cobra" };
var searchText = "cor";
var sortedList = SortedList(randomList, searchText);

foreach(string entry in sortedList)
{
    Console.Write(entry + ", ");
}
```

I get:

```
corolla, corona, pecoroll, cobra, copper, capsicum, because,
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your insight. Your interpretation of the problem was helpful and got me thinking of other possibilities when i stumbled upon other open source libraries related to fuzzy string such as https://github.com/tylerjensen/FuzzyStrings